Get Information on custom struct on the opcua server via Eclipse Milo Client
I want to populate a struct to write to an opcua server via Apache Milo. The milo client does not have any prior information on the custom data types and everything must be discovered at runtime.
The information on the struct (field names and data types) is used to consume a json, populate a struct with it and write to the server.
I added a SessionInitializer to retrieve the data type definitions at connection establishment, which works:
opcUaClient.addSessionInitializer(new DataTypeDictionarySessionInitializer(new GenericBsdParser()));

However using them to populate the struct was a struggle and seems very hacky. I get the Codec for the data type, however the internals are hidden as a private field, which I access via Reflection, which likely will break in later Java Versions (We are currently at 11):
final GenericStructCodec dataTypeCodec = 
(GenericStructCodec) client.getDynamicSerializationContext().getDataTypeManager().getCodec(dataTypeNodeId);
Field f = AbstractCodec.class.getDeclaredField("fields");
f.setAccessible(true);
Map<String, FieldType> fields = (Map<String, FieldType>) f.get(dataTypeCodec);

Using this information I parse the Json (which is already parsed to a Map in my code)
             final Struct.Builder builder = Struct.builder("ScanSettings");
                    for (final Map.Entry<String, FieldType> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        final FieldType fieldType = entry.getValue();
                        final Object jsonNode = rootNode.get(key);
                        switch (fieldType.getTypeName().toString()) {
                            case ("{http://opcfoundation.org/BinarySchema/}UInt32"):
                                builder.addMember(key, UInteger.valueOf(jsonNode.toString()));
                                break;
                            case ("{http://opcfoundation.org/BinarySchema/}String"):
                                builder.addMember(key, jsonNode);
                                break;
                            case ("{http://opcfoundation.org/BinarySchema/}Boolean"):
                                builder.addMember(key, Boolean.parseBoolean(jsonNode.toString()));
                                break;
                            case ("{urn:test:testns}CustomEnumType"):
                                final @Nullable DataTypeCodec enumTypeCodec =
                                        client.getDynamicSerializationContext()
                                                .getDataTypeManager()
                                                .getCodec(dataTypeNodeId);



                                System.err.println(dataTypeCodec);

                                builder.addMember(key, Integer.valueOf(jsonNode.toString()));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    return ExtensionObject.encode(client.getDynamicSerializationContext(),
                            builder.build(),
                            dataTypeNodeId,
                            OpcUaDefaultBinaryEncoding.getInstance());

The switch on the TypeName looks also problematic as the strings may be different I guess depending on the server implementation. Of course it misses many types and needs recursion for embedded struct, but I'm really not confident with my general approach. Is there a better way to get information on the custom data types and use them to populate a struct?

Have you looked at this example? The object you get back is a Struct https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/Struct.java

There is also a JsonBsdParser that gives you back GSON JSON objects instead.

Yeah; I am already using the Struct (or rather the builder) class and hand it over to the ExtensionObject. What do you mean "the object you get back"? Im not reading from opcua, that is already working, but trying to write to it.
Regarding the BsdParser: Isn't this how the objet gets serialized/deserialized? I do not see any more information in the JsonStructureCodecclass.

I guess I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. To write the struct back, change the value of one of its fields, then pass it to ExtensionObject.encode

Yeah I guess my working is not clear enough.  I get a Json and want to write it to a opcua server. However I do not control the json and it might have faults (wrong data types f.e.), so I want to have the data types of the fields of the struct in order to validate that the values in the json is correct. In a later step I would like to generate a JsonSchema for the unknown struct on the server, so datatypes of the fields are very important for me.

Getting this datatype metadata will be incredibly difficult in this version of Milo and OPC UA (1.03). The datatype dictionary XML format is dense and complicated. There's a reason it was deprecated and replaced with the DataTypeDefinition attribute starting in OPC UA 1.04. You're on your own here, and the BsdParser implementations are your only point of reference.

Yeah, that was my feeling. Will the DataTypeDefinition be in a future milo version? Do you have insights? I was able to get something running using the internals of the Codec classes, but it does neither feel intended nor robust tbh. Thank you for your insights.

DataTypeDefinition support is already in the dev/1.0 branch. The OpcUaClient has a DataTypeTree instance that represents the datatype hierarchy and has DataTypeDefinitions for all structured types.
